# add to the beginning of a list

Tags: dart

I have a list containing objects (i.e. `products`). I am continuously fetching new objects (`newProducts`) that I want to add at the beginning of the main list (products). I tried to simplify this in the below example:

```
void main() {
  List<Product> products = List<Product>();
  products.add(Product(3,"p3"));
  products.add(Product(4,"p4"));

  List<Product> newProducts = List<Product>();
  newProducts.add(Product(1,"p1"));
  newProducts.add(Product(2,"p2"));

  products.addAll(newProducts);
}

class Product{
  int id; String name;
  Product(this.id,this.name);
}
```

So in the end, I want the list to be like this: `[p1, p2, p3, p4]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert element at the beginning of the list in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57635916/insert-element-at-the-beginning-of-the-list-in-dart)

Comment: This question actually is not the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57635916/insert-element-at-the-beginning-of-the-list-in-dart) one. This question is about adding items in a list into the beginning of another list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/57635994/4465386:

instead of:

```
List<Product> newProducts = List<Product>();
  products.add(Product(1,"p1"));
  products.add(Product(2,"p2"));

  products.addAll(newProducts);
```

you can do:

```
products.insert(0, Product(2,"p2"));
products.insert(0, Product(1,"p1"));
```

some other options are to use `list.reverse()` to reverse a list or use list comprehension `products = [...newProducts, ...products]`